# Error npm install fibers@1.0.1 Ubuntu 12.04.4 x64

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, meteorite, fibers

When I try to deploy my meteor app with

```
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://<user>:<password>@oceanic.mongohq.com:<port>/<db_name>node bundle/main.js
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
```

When I try to install the fibers module with the commands stated on the meteor website

```
cd bundle/programs/server/node_modules
rm -r fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.1
```

I get the following errors

```
rm: cannot remove `fibers': No such file or directory
```

and then

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers

> fibers@1.0.1 install /root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

make: Entering directory `/root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:222:34: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:222:45: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:241:34: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:241:45: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:279:40: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:279:51: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:300:36: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:300:47: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:468:37: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:468:48: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:510:65: error: ‘AccessorInfo’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:510:79: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘info’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:518:65: error: ‘AccessorInfo’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:518:79: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘info’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:529:66: error: ‘AccessorInfo’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:529:80: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘info’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:533:77: error: ‘AccessorInfo’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:533:91: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘info’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:540:71: error: ‘AccessorInfo’ does not name a type
../src/fibers.cc:540:85: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘info’ with no type [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static void Fiber::DestroyOrphans()’:
../src/fibers.cc:202:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >&)’
../src/fibers.cc:202:41: note: candidates are:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1861:5: note: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(const v8::String::Utf8Value&)
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1861:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >’ to ‘const v8::String::Utf8Value&’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1851:14: note: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Handle<v8::Value>)
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1851:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >’ to ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::New(const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:223:13: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:225:22: error: invalid types ‘const int[int]’ for array subscript
../src/fibers.cc:227:21: error: request for member ‘IsConstructCall’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:228:37: error: invalid types ‘const int[int]’ for array subscript
../src/fibers.cc:229:16: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >’
../src/fibers.cc:232:55: error: invalid types ‘const int[int]’ for array subscript
../src/fibers.cc:233:19: error: request for member ‘This’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:234:16: error: request for member ‘This’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::Run(const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:242:30: error: request for member ‘Holder’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:249:20: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:266:14: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:267:50: error: invalid types ‘const int[int]’ for array subscript
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::ThrowInto(const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:280:30: error: request for member ‘Holder’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:284:20: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:286:20: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:287:49: error: invalid types ‘const int[int]’ for array subscript
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::Reset(const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:301:30: error: request for member ‘Holder’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:307:20: error: request for member ‘Length’ in ‘args’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
../src/fibers.cc:316:29: error: conversion from ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ requested
../src/fibers.cc: In member function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::ReturnYielded()’:
../src/fibers.cc:383:24: error: conversion from ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ requested
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static void Fiber::RunFiber(void**)’:
../src/fibers.cc:396:10: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:768:13: error: ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()’ is private
../src/fibers.cc:406:17: error: within this context
../src/fibers.cc:418:20: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>’
../src/fibers.cc:425:9: error: ‘args’ was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:427:23: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >’
../src/fibers.cc:427:45: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>’
../src/fibers.cc:429:23: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >’
../src/fibers.cc:429:45: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>’
../src/fibers.cc:455:20: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>’
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value>
```

```
../src/fibers.cc:587:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const int&)’ to ‘v8::AccessorGetterCallback {aka void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)}’ [-fpermissive]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2098:8: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘bool v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:588:75: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const int&)’ to ‘v8::AccessorGetterCallback {aka void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)}’ [-fpermissive]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2098:8: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘bool v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:588:75: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const int&)’ to ‘v8::AccessorSetterCallback {aka void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&)}’ [-fpermissive]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2098:8: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘bool v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ [-fpermissive]
../src/fibers.cc:589:72: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const int&)’ to ‘v8::AccessorGetterCallback {aka void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)}’ [-fpermissive]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2098:8: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘bool v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ [-fpermissive]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In function ‘void init(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:768:13: error: ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()’ is private
../src/fibers.cc:614:14: error: within this context
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Object]’:
../src/fibers.cc:123:35:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Object>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Object*’
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Function]’:
../src/fibers.cc:124:27:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Function>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Function>’ to ‘v8::Function*’
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Context]’:
../src/fibers.cc:125:43:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Context>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Context>’ to ‘v8::Context*’
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T>&) [with T = v8::Object]’:
../src/fibers.cc:136:32:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >::Dispose(v8::Isolate*&)’
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note: void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Dispose() [with T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T>&) [with T = v8::Function]’:
../src/fibers.cc:137:28:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >::Dispose(v8::Isolate*&)’
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note: void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Dispose() [with T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T>&) [with T = v8::Context]’:
../src/fibers.cc:138:36:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Context>::Dispose(v8::Isolate*&)’
../src/fibers.cc:34:3: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note: void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Dispose() [with T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:588:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘void uni::MakeWeak(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T>&, P*) [with void (* F)(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >, void*) = Fiber::WeakCallback, T = v8::Object, P = Fiber]’:
../src/fibers.cc:146:53:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:39:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >::MakeWeak(v8::Isolate*&, Fiber*&, void (*)(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >, void*))’
../src/fibers.cc:39:3: note: candidates are:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:646:3: note: template<class S, class P> void v8::Persistent::MakeWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakReferenceCallbacks<S, P>::Revivable) [with S = S, P = P, T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, typename v8::WeakReferenceCallbacks<S, P>::Revivable = <type error>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:653:3: note: template<class P> void v8::Persistent::MakeWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakReferenceCallbacks<T, P>::Revivable) [with P = P, T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, typename v8::WeakReferenceCallbacks<T, P>::Revivable = <type error>]
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Primitive]’:
../src/fibers.cc:269:55:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Primitive, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Primitive> >::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Primitive>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Primitive, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Primitive>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Primitive>’ to ‘v8::Primitive*’
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Value]’:
../src/fibers.cc:339:63:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Value>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ to ‘v8::Value*’
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate]’:
../src/fibers.cc:561:55:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>&)’
../src/fibers.cc:30:44: note: candidate is:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note: static T* v8::Persistent<T, M>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate>]
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5591:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>’ to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate*’
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/src/node.h:61:0,
                 from ../src/coroutine.h:1,
                 from ../src/fibers.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Object]’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:474:5:   instantiated from ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent*) [with S = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, T = v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5608:3:   instantiated from ‘void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Object, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:546:5:   instantiated from ‘v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, v8::Persistent<T, M> = v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >]’
../src/fibers.cc:129:19:   instantiated from here
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:478:5: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘v8::Object* volatile’ in assignment
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Function]’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:474:5:   instantiated from ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent*) [with S = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>, T = v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5608:3:   instantiated from ‘void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Function, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>, T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:546:5:   instantiated from ‘v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>, v8::Persistent<T, M> = v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >]’
../src/fibers.cc:129:19:   instantiated from here
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:478:5: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘v8::Object* volatile’ in assignment
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Context]’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:474:5:   instantiated from ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent*) [with S = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>, T = v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<v8::Context>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5608:3:   instantiated from ‘void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Context, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>, T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:546:5:   instantiated from ‘v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>, v8::Persistent<T, M> = v8::Persistent<v8::Context>]’
../src/fibers.cc:129:19:   instantiated from here
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:478:5: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘v8::Object* volatile’ in assignment
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Value]’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:474:5:   instantiated from ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent*) [with S = v8::Primitive, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Primitive>, T = v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5608:3:   instantiated from ‘void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Primitive, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Primitive>, T = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:558:5:   instantiated from ‘v8::Persistent<T, M>& v8::Persistent<T, M>::operator=(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Primitive, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Primitive>, T = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>, v8::Persistent<T, M> = v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >]’
../src/fibers.cc:269:55:   instantiated from here
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:478:5: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘v8::Object* volatile’ in assignment
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::FunctionTemplate]’:
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:474:5:   instantiated from ‘static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent*) [with S = v8::FunctionTemplate, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate>, T = v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::NonCopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5608:3:   instantiated from ‘void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::FunctionTemplate, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate>, T = v8::FunctionTemplate, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate>]’
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:553:5:   instantiated from ‘v8::Persistent<T, M>& v8::Persistent<T, M>::operator=(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate>, v8::Persistent<T, M> = v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >]’
../src/fibers.cc:561:55:   instantiated from here
/root/.node-gyp/0.11.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:478:5: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘v8::Object* volatile’ in assignment
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate]’:
../src/fibers.cc:31:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Function]’:
../src/fibers.cc:31:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::GetCurrent(v8::Local<v8::String>, const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:524:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Value]’:
../src/fibers.cc:31:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T> uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Primitive]’:
../src/fibers.cc:31:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::New(const int&)’:
../src/fibers.cc:235:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1045:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fibers@1.0.1"
npm ERR! cwd /root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/mt_5/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of googeling i came to [this](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/166).

Node-fibers doesn't support intermediary releases, therefore you need to use 0.10.x branch or supported 11.x release!